# Fourier-Mukai transforms on stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

I have "generic" questions about Fourier-Mukai transforms.

**Question 1:** Does there exist a well-defined notion of Fourier-Mukai transform on (Deligne-Mumford) stacks?

**Question 2:** Do there exist papers in which this notion is deeply studied?

Comment: Perhaps, http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210439 would help?

Comment: Or https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.0157